# Transform rows of pandas Dataframe into list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

How can I transform rows of Pandas dataframe into list of strings? I want to map each row of data frame into string such as it contains name of column and value of column for selected columns of dataframe:

for example I would like to convert columns B,C,D into list of strings (result) as is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
A=[1,2,3,4]
B=[5,6,7,8]
C=[2,3,4,5]
D=[4,5,6,7]
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[A,B,C,D]).transpose()
df.columns=['A','B','C','D']
print df

   A  B  C  D
0  1  5  2  4
1  2  6  3  5
2  3  7  4  6
3  4  8  5  7

result=['B:5,C:2,D:4','B:6,C:3,D:5','B:7,C:4,D:6','B:5,C:2,D:4','B:8,C:5,D:7']
print
print result

['B:5,C:2,D:4', 'B:6,C:3,D:5', 'B:7,C:4,D:6', 'B:5,C:2,D:4', 'B:8,C:5,D:7']
```

Edit: format of the string does not need to be exactly as in my example as long as it contains column names and values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it is the best way but this will do what you want:

```
cols = ["B", "C", "D"]
[",".join("{}:{}".format(*t) for t in zip(cols, row)) for _, row in df[cols].iterrows()]
```

Which will give you:

```
['B:5,C:2,D:4', 'B:6,C:3,D:5', 'B:7,C:4,D:6', 'B:8,C:5,D:7']
```

Comment: It does work using python3 but based on your prints you don't seem to be using python3